# Base64 encode .rtf and .pdf type files - Java/Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Question, I have an implementation that requires both .pdf/.rft files to be Base64 encoded. The .pdf file types work great, but the .rft files do not. I assume it must be possible to Base64 encode the .rft media hex based files, but I'm not sure if using the method below will work or if something else is required. Does someone know? I might need to convert the .rtf byte array to .pdf before encoding if that is possible.

```
String fileData = "e1xydGYxXGFu..."
return( Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(fileData.bytes) )
```

Comment: media hex based files in String?? that's a point where you lose data. just read file content as bytes.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the bytes conversion on the encodeToString above. Yes, I agree. So is it possible tp Base64 encode an .rtf and .pdf file the same way. The .rtf files are media files, so don't they have to be hex encoded first before they can be base64 encoded. Could you let me know.

Comment: base64 is an algorithm to convert bytes to ascii string and back. you should read file data as bytes directly from file : `byte[] fileData = file.getBytes()` and then use Base64 encoder. in bytes it does not matter what do you  have - rtf, pdf, jpg, ...

Comment: Ok, thanks that makes sense.